# APK signing certificates expire too soon - error on Google Play

Tags: android, cordova, apk, visual-studio-cordova

Hi i'll send my first apk to Google play, and i'm receiving this message

error: certificates expire too soon, send other apk.

My apk is signed how you can see , image below. Is an cordova apk ,made in visual studio.

[image]

Comment: Your signing key is set to expire in 2020, if I am interpreting those dates correctly. Quoting [the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html), "Important: Your application must be signed with a cryptographic key whose validity period ends after 22 October 2033."

Comment: okay , but i've used  >>   -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

Comment: Then perhaps Visual Studio is not using that keystore. I have not used Visual Studio in 16 years, and so I cannot advise you on how to get Visual Studio to sign with your desired keystore.